# How to Filter Data following Table List

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table list and I would like to use data in Table List to Filter in another table. How can I write in VBA Code ? I'm not good with Array Function

**For Example.**

Table List

[image]

and Filter in another Table

[image]

I would Like to Filter All Name in the above Table

Filter Name A

[image]

and Count the amount to Report

[image]

Filter Name B

[image]

and Count the amount to Report

[image]

Summary Report

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem did you have getting it to work?

Comment: Pls. never post data  to reproduce as screenshot. Use instead [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/), or at least post them as text (of code).

Comment: have you tried using a pivot table?

Comment: Use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Comment: Better still [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table.